# Intellij IDEA SQL autocomplete quotes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have properly configured Datasource in IntelliJ IDEA and I've successfuly tested the connection. I use mysql and I have set all the files to MySQL language.

Now when I try to write SQL simply into a String like this:

```
connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DeliveryInformation ...");
```

It won't suggest anything, nor autocomplete ! However when I type

```
connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 'DeliveryInformation' ...");
```

then inside those quotes, autocomplete works. But SQL with quotes gives me a syntax error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Single quotes around table names are invalid in SQL - even in MySQL.

Comment: Do you use Ctrl+Space to get code completion?

Comment: What version and edition of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Version 12.1.4 - I've just got an update today ;) Yes I use ctrl+space to get code completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out already. SQL code completion started to work after setting injection-language to "keywords" (default) and then to MySQL again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the your code. If still there is a error some thing wrong with your code. else hit Alt+Enter and disable Inspection will solve that syntax problem. this is not a actual error.

No need to put single quotation for table name.. that will be the issue.

Comment: I am probably being misunderstood. I know the right SQL syntax, my trouble is NOT disabling the code inspection, but turning code completion on.